# evaluate sh source code, output is not displayed well

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, shell-command

When I evaluate this:

```
#+begin_src sh
brew list
#+end_src
```

The result is good:

[image]

However, if I use:

```
#+begin_src sh
brew info emacs
#+end_src
```

I get something weird:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is simply wrapping try calling  <kbd>M-x</kbd>  `toggle-truncate-lines`

Comment: I used the visual line mode. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the reason. The result should be fine. It is the problem my screen size. Because the result is generated in the form of table. If the width of this table is bigger than the emacs window size, the table will reconstruct in another way just like in my screenshot 2.